# Смешать все ключи массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, примерно такой (для удобства примера показываю только 3 ключа, a b c), на самом деле ключей гораздо больше.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

На выходе нужно что бы получилось такое, обязательным условием является, чтобы значения были только 3-х символьные.

```
Array(
[0] => aaa
[1] => aab
[2] => aac
[3] => aba
[4] => abb
[5] => abc
[6] => aca
[7] => acb
[8] => acc
[9] => baa
[10] => bab
[11] => bac
[12] => bba
[13] => bbb
[14] => bbc
[15] => bca
[16] => bcb
[17] => bcc
[18] => caa
[19] => cab
[20] => cac
[21] => cba
[22] => cbb
[23] => cbc
[24] => cca
[25] => ccb
[26] => ccc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать рекурсивный подход. Функция ниже сгенерирует комбинации любой указанной длины из любого массива

```
function combine($source, $max_len = 3, $key_part = '')
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($source as $value)
    {
        if (strlen($key_part.$value) >= $max_len)
        {
            $result[] = substr($key_part.$value, 0, $max_len);
        }
        else
        {
            $result = array_merge($result, combine($source, $max_len, $key_part.$value));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Использование

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$keys = combine($array, 3);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($keys, 1).'</pre>';

$array = array('a', 'b');
$keys = combine($array, 6);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($keys, 1).'</pre>';
```

**UPD:** Добавил аргумент $trim - в нём можно указывать символы, которые не должны быть в начале или конце ключа

```
function combine($source, $max_len = 3, $trim = '', $key_part = '')
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($source as $value)
    {
        if (strlen($key_part.$value) >= $max_len)
        {
            if (!strlen($trim) || $key_part.$value == trim($key_part.$value, $trim))
            {
                $result[] = substr($key_part.$value, 0, $max_len);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $result = array_merge($result, combine($source, $max_len, $trim, $key_part.$value));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', '-', '+');
$keys = combine($array, 3, '-+');
echo '<pre>'.print_r($keys, 1).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Похоже Ваш код работает, только у меня в $result = []; - ошибка, может так должно быть? $result[] = ''; Или нет? И еще в ключах есть пустые значения, как их удалить? С ними не могу понять на 100% рабочий ли код?

Comment: Здначит у вас более старая версия php. Замените `$result = [];` на `$result = array();`

Comment: Пустых значений быть не может. Разве что вы добавили `$result[] = '';`, тогда это и есть пустое значение

Comment: Да, тогда все отлично!

Comment: К Вам еще 1 вопрос, надеюсь сдесь можно задать Вам лично. В массиве $array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'); вместо 'd' знак тирэ '-'. Нужно изменить Ваш рекурсивный код, чтоб по краям не выводилось тирэ. Например эти значения не правильны и удаляются: -00v ; 000- ; -00-

Comment: Переделал - смотрите в ответе

Comment: И самая последняя просьба. Надеюсь поймете меня. Из получившегося массива нужно удалить ключи в которых 2 и более идущих за собой подряд знака минус, например запрещено:  0--v; 0---0; 0----0;

Comment: Для этого пройдитесь по результату и удалите из массива все значения, где есть двойные минусы

Answer (score 0):

Генерируем массив, где все комбинации и shuffle(перемешивает).